# Makefile missing separator. Stop. error with eval and variables

Tags: makefile

THIS IS NOT A SPACES VS. TABS ISSUE.

I'm writing a few Make targets to run Terraform and Helm in sequence, and I need to capture part of the Terraform output to pass along to the subsequent Helm target. This is what I've got so far:

```
TF        := terraform
RND_ENV   := deployment/envs/rnd
RND_PLAN  := tfplan-rnd.out
RND_APPLY := tfapply-rnd.out

.PHONY: init-rnd plan-rnd apply-rnd deploy-rnd

init-rnd:
    @$(TF) init $(RND_ENV)

plan-rnd: init-rnd
    @$(TF) plan -out=$(RND_PLAN) $(RND_ENV)

apply-rnd: plan-rnd
    $(TF) apply -no-color $(RND_PLAN) | tee $(RND_APPLY)
    $(shell grep my_output_var $(RND_APPLY) | awk '{print $$3}' > .my_output_var)
    @rm $(RND_APPLY)

# ...further steps omitted...
```

Once again, I can assure you that I am using TABS instead of SPACES in my Makefile. I have checked and double-checked. However when I run `make apply-rnd`, it successfully runs the `init-rnd` target, successfully runs the `plan-rnd` target, but then breaks on the first line of that target with the following message:

> Makefile:15: *** missing separator.  Stop.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the pipe? Or perhaps the use of variables?

Anyways, these same commands work when I run them manually in Bash... I just need to get them working here in this Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `eval` here at all?  The `eval` function is intended to evaluate *makefiles*.  You are trying to pass it shell commands, which are not makefile syntax, so you get errors.

Just run the commands in the shell: remove the `eval` function.

Comment: I had added the eval in an attempt to get it working. I get the exact same error even when it's not present. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: You should remove the `$(shell...)` as well.  You're already in a shell: just type the command you want to run.  It's a big anti-pattern to use `eval` or `shell` inside a recipe.  However I can't understand your comments here.  This error happens while make is _parsing_ the makefile and make always parses the entire makefile before it starts to build any targets.  So you should see it every single time you run make, regardless of what target you try to to build.

Comment: I understand that.  Please see the second part of my comment.  If indeed you see this error only when you run some `make xxxx` commands but not others that means that there is something going on here that you haven't shown us.  Maybe there's a recursive make call, or you include a makefile only when some targets are given on the command line, or something else.  I recommend you run with `make -d` and try to see what the difference is here.

Comment: Nevermind, I was completely wrong. I was getting misled because I assumed the line number in the Makefile error was telling me the problem was happening on that same line. However Removing shell from the line that follows it did, indeed, fix the issue.